# Why do I need to @import my SCSS files more than once to prevent errors?

Tags: import, sass

I'm using some third party styles that is provided in SCSS format. I'm customizing it a good deal, so I'm using the SCSS as opposed to importing the CSS into my SCSS files.

Here is the architecture of my SCSS files.

```
> scss (folder)
> --third-party-code (folder)
> ----extras (folder)
> ------jquery.plugin.header.scss
> ------jquery.plugin.footer.scss
> ----third-party-code-main.scss (includes imports)
> --modules (folder)
> ----_header.scss
> ----_footer.scss
> ----_navigation.scss
> --_third-party-code.scss
> --_modules.scss (includes imports)
> --styles.scss (includes imports)
```

Can someone tell me why I keep getting these "mixin", "variable" or "sprite" not defined if I don't @import the SCSS files where I define my variables, mixins and sprites?

Doing this is causing two of the same sprite images to appear in my CSS which is breaking my images that use sprites on the page.

Why are the third party SCSS files being treated differently than SCSS files that I include in my "scss/modules" directory?

Let me know if I need to include any additional information.

Comment: you should add underscore prefix to your third party files same as the files in modules, then import them

Comment: That did the trick! If you add your response as an answer, I'll mark it as the selected answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add underscore prefix to your third party files same as the files in modules, then import them. Glad it helped~